# Hola, he estado intentando aplicar a una etiqueta un :hover en CSS, pero no me funciona. Les mi codigo de HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

estoy haciendo una página web en Visual Studio Code. Resulta que tengo en el div "cuerpo" tengo una etiqueta . En CSS, quise hacer un :hover para cuando pusiera mi mouse encima de , el color de las letras y el fondo cambiara de color, pero resulta que no hace el efecto.

Yo utilizo Edge, pero intenté con Chrome y tampoco funcionó. Anteriormente me servía, por lo que supuse que es un error en alguna línea de código, aunque probé en comentar algunas líneas para ver si era alguna línea de código el error.

Al final no encontré el error y decidí subir esto acá por si alguien puede decirme qué es lo que está pasando.

De ante mano les agradezco. Les dejo el código de HTML y CSS.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/style.css">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <section id="contenedor">
       <img src="./recursos/fotoPrincipal.png" alt="fotoPrincipal" id="fotoPrincipal">
       <div id="navegador">
           <nav>
               <img src="./recursos/logoBlanco.png" alt="logoBlanco" id="logoBlanco">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">Misión</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">Visión</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
               </ul>
           </nav>
       </div>

       <div id="cuerpo">
           <h1>Somos su <br>mejor opción</h1>
           <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Culpa magnam velit ipsum deserunt cupiditate
               accusamus, a fugiat quaerat fuga neque ipsa. Facilis iure perferendis in sint. Quas, libero modi! Quis?
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid explicabo, nisi recusandae nemo
               incidunt iusto! Veritatis, culpa nulla. Aliquid unde est facere officia maxime eos ab voluptatem ratione
               cupiditate hic?
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non numquam quo exercitationem cumque
               asperiores excepturi quia mollitia adipisci, repudiandae magnam minus nesciunt nihil dolor eius. Quas
               soluta modi nesciunt officia!
           </p>
           <a href="#">Ver Misión</a>
       </div>
   </section>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: url(#fotoPrincipal);
} */

#contenedor {
    position: absolute;
    height: 800px;
}

#fotoPrincipal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
}

#logoBlanco {
    margin-top: -20px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    max-width: fit-content;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul {
    margin-left: 550px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

nav a::before,
nav a::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

nav a::before {
    top: -5px;
    left: 27px;
}

nav a::after {
    bottom: -7px;
    right: -27px;
}

nav a:hover::before {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

nav a:hover::after {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

#cuerpo h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 180px;
    left: 60px;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
}

#cuerpo p {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    bottom: 320px;
    left: 750px;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    line-height: 27px;
}

#cuerpo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 204, 255);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 750px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 700px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#cuerpo a :hover{
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(183, 4, 4, 0.868);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es respecto al hover de la etiqueta `a` que se encuentra dentro de `#cuerpo`, es debido a que tienes un espacio donde no debería ir.
Te dejo aquí la corrección:

```
#cuerpo a:hover{
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(183, 4, 4, 0.868);
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias hermano. Estuve como loco intentando corregirlo. Al fin se pudo.

Comment: Si te sirvió mi respuesta @JosephCarazo no olvides marcarla como respuesta aceptada, así ayudas a la comunidad en caso de que alguien tenga el mismo problema c: